# Gecko Driver 0.9 Firefox hangs after driver.get

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, webdriver

I am using Firefox Developer Edition 49.0a2 and I am able to open the web browser but after driver.get("example.website.com") executes, it just loads the page and hangs there. The test does not fail or error out.

I've tried using Marionette Driver and it doesn't even interact with the browser. I have also tried the different variations of the constructor such as FirefoxDriver(FFbinary, FFprofile, FFcapabilities) and the others that only require one or two of the parameters in all possible permutations. The developer edition of Firefox is where I get the best results as Firefox 47.0 is explicitly not supported.

Answer (score 0):

i face the same issue so i tried to update the Windows OS and checked again
it worked fine for me.
Gecko driver might not be compatible if we do not update OS as well
Check it once if it help

Comment: Chasing the problem with a try this try that is not really an answer. If possible try to be more specific (version x of Gecko needs version y of OS), or provide these as commentaries to the existing question or answers.